# Windows RDP Server farm redirection stops working

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2

We have a RDP Server farm based on Window 2008R2 servers with DNS round robin. That is, people make a connection to "myfarmname", which first takes them to the ip of some "farmmemberX.mydomain.local" and then they are redirected to some "farmmemberY.mydomain.com" according to load. That's also how everything workd until yesterday.

As of today, most users experience problems and cannot connect to the farm, usually with an error message like this (translated from German):

> Remote desktop connection cannot connect to remote computer.
>
> From remote computer "myfarmname", with which you want to make a connection, you are redirected to remote computer "farmmemberX.mydomain.local". It cannot be verified if both remote computers belong to the same remote desktop server farm. You must use the farm name, not the computer name, if you want to mak a connection to a remote desktop server farm.
>
> Contact a network administrator to obtain support if you use a RDP connection that was prepared by the administrator.
>
> If yo want to connect with a specific farm member, use "mstsc /admin"

As you can see, I **do** use the farm name - but I still fail, with settings that worked yesterday. Changes are possibly updates and stuff, but nothing regarding configurations.

How can I correct this misbehaviour?
My only workaround currently is to provoke the above "myfarmname"/"farmmemberX" error and then try a connect to farmmemberX (which apparently is the currently preferred target) and then connect diretly to farmmemberX.

---

Overview of settings of the RDP servers:

Tab Remote desktop connection broker:

```
Server usage: farm member
Remote desktop connection broker: MYBROKER
Farm name: myfarmname
```

RDP tcp:

```
Security: Negotiate
Encrpytion: client compatible
Allow only NLA: not checked
certificate: valid, issued from internal CA
```

Comment: SuperUser does not support corporate networking questions.

Comment: Voted to migrate to ServerFault...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this, but... As far as I remember, you need to deploy a certificate on each of the endpoints for server authentication. In that case, I would check if any of the certs has expired.

/cd