# Remote Desktop Services Broker - Stuck on Securing Session

Tags: windows-server-2012

[Related topic](https://serverfault.com/questions/676353/remote-desktop-server-farm-stops-working)

Ok, So I have searched the site for solutions, and the problem in the related topic seems to match my issue, however, I do not want to hijack the thread with my own issue.
I have attempted the solution in the related topic, but the offending Update (KB33002567) is not installed on either the main server or our RDS Gateway/Broker
99% of users are connecting with no issue, but some users are getting stuck on "Securing Session"

This is on Server 2012 Datacentre with Windows 8.1 Virtual Desktops.

I have also tried the solution in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/676525/windows-rdp-server-farm-redirection-stops-working)
but it still results in "securing sesssion"

My event log shows errors like this

```
Remote Desktop Connection Broker Client failed while getting redirection packet from Connection Broker.
User : Domain\User.name
Error: Element not found.
```

and

```
Remote Desktop Connection Broker Client failed to redirect the user Domain\User.name. 
Error: NULL
```

EDIT:
As an update, since I wrote this question, all users are now logged in. But it still took quite a bit of effort